# How to use function from class Python in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Python class with methods inside. One of them is public.

How to apply this method in filtering rows data in Pandas?

I meaan something like this:

```
class Math:
   def isTrue(value):
     return True
```

Pandas rule:

```
df[df["name"].apply(Math.isTrue)]
```

If values in column name are `True` show them in result dataframe.

Data is:

```
Number Name    Country
1      Vasila  US
1212     oLGA    AU
6      Fors    RE
```

I need to filter all rows where Number has double pair like `1212` using my custom method from class with regex.

Result should be:

```
Number Name    Country
1212     oLGA    AU
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. What happens when you try your code? How is that different from what is supposed to happen? Please read [ask] and [mre].

Comment: Also please provide an example of data to use with your code and the expected output

Comment: Done, you can see

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
import re

class Matcher:
    pattern = re.compile('^(?P<num_pair>\d\d)(?(num_pair)(?P=num_pair))$')
    
    @classmethod
    def has_num_pair(cls, n: int) -> bool:
        if cls.pattern.match(str(n)) is None:
            return False
        return True
```

```py
df[df['Number'].apply(Matcher.has_num_pair)]
```

Regex explanation:

```py
pattern = re.compile(
    '^'                    # at the beginning of the string
    '(?P<num_pair>'        # create a capturing group named "num_pair" ...
        '\d\d)'            # ... that captures two digits
    '(?(num_pair)'         # if the group "num_pair" captures something ...
        '(?P=num_pair))'   # try to match the captured content again
    '$'                    # the string must end after that
)
```

This pattern will match numbers that are made of a repeated pair of digits, like `1212`, `9898`or `3535`, but it will **not** match numbers that *include* such a pair along with other digits, like `14343`for example. If you want to match those too, change your regex as such:

```py
pattern = re.compile('.*(?P<num_pair>\d\d)(?(num_pair)(?P=num_pair)).*')
```

This variant will also match `14343`, `767689`and so on.